# Rest api problem with mongoDB 1100 but in second request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

First request when i use postman always work, second request is always fail.

This is user schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    city: { type: String },
    delivery: { type: String },
    name: { type: String },
    phone: { type: Number },
    zip: { type: String },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Register user route:

```js
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
      req.body.password,
      process.env.PASS_SEC
    ).toString(),
    city: req.body.city,
    delivery: req.body.delivery,
    name: req.body.name,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    zip: req.body.zip,
  });

  try {
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Postman user register request, always work:

```
{
    "username":"tambo2",
    "email":"tambo2@gmail.com",
    "password":"tambo1233",
    "city": "Wsks2",
    "delivery": "kolkowa 384",
    "name": "samsons1",
    "phone": "500600702",
    "zip": "30-502"
}
```

When i do second request to make another user, always is problem:

```
{
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "keyPattern": {
        "adress": 1
    },
    "keyValue": {
        "adress": null
    }
}
```

Problem 1100 is duplicate problem, but always a have not this same data, and required is only username, email and password.

First request work, when i make second request and try make new user always is problem. If i drop db in mongo and try again with 0 user i can make another one.

[First post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrknS.png)

[Second post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTF16.png)

Comment: Are you changing all of the values for the unique fields on the 2nd request? FYI using a unique constraint on a password field is a recipe for disaster

Comment: In second request i change all data not only unique, and i change unique for password you are right it's will be disaster with more than 2 users.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your questions to show examples of the successful and failing requests in Postman? Screenshots are fine

Comment: I added screenshots

Comment: Are you sure you're running the code in your question? If you've made changes, you might not have restarted your Express server. The field identified by the error (`adress`) doesn't exist in your schema

Comment: I delete colection, and make new now is start worki fine. Thank u Phil for help.

Comment: I thought you said you tried that already... _"If i drop db in mongo"_ 

Comment: Yes i delete all users, but i dont delete colection. Now i delete colection, and start working.

Comment: Can you show what `console.log(req.body);` prints on your end-point?